Specify a more permissive Cross-Origin Resource Policy to prevent a resource from being blocked
I'm working on a fullstack-app (PHP/React JS/ graphQL). I'm trying to deploy the app to 000webhost but received this error. I checked the network  and I received 200 status response but the data are coming as html format no as a JSON.

Could help me anyone please?

The message you are sharing is likely not the reason for the fact that your responses are HTML instead of JSON. I think you are focusing on the wrong thing. Typically getting HTML instead of your expected JSON response might indicate a genuine error which results in an HTML error message being returned in which case you should check what the response content actually is for hints on what's wrong

Please include error messages and text as text and code, not only as screenshots. (For accessibility, readability, and discoverability.)

If you receive a response as 200 OK then the request response is received fine. CORP issues would block the request. It would not return 200 OK.

You have two errors: first, you have a CORS issue, which results in your browser blocking a request to an outside resource. Second, your webpage sends some request to an API which responds with an HTML content whereas your webpage expected a JSON to be returned.
In order to resolve both issues, you need to address them separately:

CORS issue: if you own the end point where you wanted to request to and the request was blocked, then specify an appropriate Access-Control-Allow-Origin value. If you do not own it, then you will need to reach out to the owners and ask them to send that response header for your requests
API issue: Find out whether the HTML is a proper response from the API. If so, then modify your webpage to access HTML as proper response. If not, then make sure the API responds with proper JSON

